# Why does RuboCop not ignore the file 'schema.rb' in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, rubocop

RuboCop does not ignore the file `schema.rb` despite configuring its `YAML` file to exclude it.

### How do I configure it to ignore schema.rb?

The following is a snippet of the code from the file `.rubocop.yml`:

```yaml
require: rubocop-rails
require: rubocop-performance

AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'script/**/*'
    - 'bin/{rails,rake}'
    - 'vendor/**/*'
    - 'spec/fixtures/**/*'
    - 'tmp/**/*'
    - 'Gemfile.lock'

Rails:
  Enabled: true

Layout/SpaceAroundEqualsInParameterDefault:
  EnforcedStyle: no_space

Naming/VariableNumber:
  EnforcedStyle: normalcase

Style/StringLiterals:
  EnforcedStyle: double_quotes

Style/SymbolArray:
  Enabled: true
```

Comment: Can you please include some or all of the output of `rubocop --debug`? The part at the top listing active config files would be helpful, and so would the "Scanning" lines relevant to your `db` folder.

Answer (score 3):

`rubocop-rails` now automatically ignores `db/schema.rb`. This was introduced in [version 2.4.1](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rails/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#241-2019-12-25).

In addition, rather than using separate `require` statements for each RuboCop extension, you should provide them as an array to ensure that all extensions are loaded. For example:

```rb
require:
    - rubocop-rails
    - rubocop-performance
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added only

```
AllCops:
  Excludes:
    - config/unicorn.rb
    - db/**

Style/Documentation:
...
```

and rubocop is worked

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same confusion.. In my case, this was not actually a Rubocop issue. Running `rails db:migrate` was causing schema to be recreated and the column positions adjusted.